# how to implement sticky scrolling with angular and ionic v1

Tags: html, css, angularjs, ionic-framework, positioning

I need some help in implementing a two part content area in the following way:

1. if the bottom part is not in the "view" it's upper side will stick to the bottom (blue part in the image)
2. while we scroll down it remains at the bottom
3. if the user scrolls enough to the second part position it loses its stickiness and scrolls with the flow.

I can't use the footer to do so because it is not in the scroll content flow
in addition, absolute positioning also have its issues due to ionic translate in CSS

[two part scroll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKIfo.png)

Comment: please share part of the code you have done so far, or make a jsfiddle or codepen for it

Comment: actually I haven't done much, I am thinking of it's architecture. 
i.e. I have to listen to the container scroll event to see if the directive is indeed in view and if it is add/remove a sticky class from it.
the problem is how will it be sticky to an unknown container that lives in a css translation